# How do I find the maximum difference within a nonempty list

Tags: python, list

The question is to write a function max_diff that consumes a nonempty list of numbers and produces the maximum difference between any two elements in the list. I was having difficulty getting to show the max, the min and how to subtract the max from the min.
This is my code so far:

```
seq = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def max_diff(seq):
    min1 = seq[0]
    max1 = seq[-1]

print("min", min1, seq.index(min))
print("max", max1, seq.index(max))
print("maxdiff", max1 - min1)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your efforts, and *then* share where you're having problems with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For starters, you never call `max_diff`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the minimum and maximum values using `min` and `max` functions, then get the difference in between them.

```
min1 = min(seq)
max1 = max(seq)
maxDiff = max1-min1
```

You can do this inside a function as well:

```
def getMaxDiff(seq):
    return max(seq)-min(seq)
```

Comment: "...write a function max_diff..."

Answer (score 2):

You can not access min1 out of def scope.